# How to add tr (row) with dynamic td (column) to table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, html-table

I have a question about dynamic `tr` with keep the content of `td`.

I have a table like flowing code:

```
<table id="map2">
    <tr>
        <td class="15c">15</td>
        <td class="16c">16</td>
        <td class="17c">17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="15c">15</td>
        <td class="16c">16</td>
        <td class="17c">17</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I added some jQuery code that create a column dynamically. Like flowing code:

```
$('#map2').on('mouseenter', 'td:last-child', function(){
            var tdClass = $(this).attr('class');
            var newClass = parseInt(tdClass);
            if(newClass <= 30) {
                $(this).after('<td class="'+ (newClass+1) +'c">'+ (newClass+1) +'</td><td class="'+ (newClass+2) +'c">'+ (newClass+2) +'</td><td class="'+ (newClass+3) +'c">'+ (newClass+3) +'</td>');
            } else {
                alert('end!')
            }
        });

        $('#map2').on('mouseenter', 'td:first-child', function(){
            var tdClass = $(this).attr('class');
            var newClass = parseInt(tdClass);
            if(newClass >= 3) {
                $(this).before('<td class="'+ (newClass-3) +'c">'+ (newClass-3) +'</td><td class="'+ (newClass-2) +'c">'+ (newClass-2) +'</td><td class="'+ (newClass-1) +'c">'+ (newClass-1) +'</td>');
            } else {
                alert('end!')
            }
        });
```

That code create a `td` for me, now I want to create a `tr` (row) with keep the content. For example when the new row was created, that had content like before `td` in before `tr`.
I tried some code like this:

```
$('#map2').on('mouseenter', 'tr:first-child', function(){
            var trCont = $(this).html;
            // $(this).before('<tr>'+ trCont +'</tr>');
            $(this).before('<tr><td>new row</td></tr>');
        });
```

but didn't work.
How can I solve this problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/H6MSS/2/

Comment: Try `var trCont = $(this).html()`.

Comment: i try that but dident work. so i made it comment :(

Comment: but `$(this).html()` is a first step. because `$(this).html` would be an undefined property.

Comment: `$().html()` is a function, so that should be correct. Disregard my previous comment here, I mis-read the selectors >.<.

Comment: you can try it on http://jsfiddle.net/H6MSS/2/

Comment: I've played with your code on JSFiddle, and I think the issue comes with the event you are using. As soon as a new row is made, the event is triggered again since your mouse has entered the new row (which is now the first row). It appears to work, but just very quickly (if that is what you intend).

Comment: i put it there that i test the code. so it create. but i want that when a new `tr` created , that have content like flowing `tr`...